# Deserializing JSON into C# Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am trying to deserialize a json object into c# object and list the Itinerary items.

Here is my json object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "Itineraries": [
        {
           "isDomestic": false,
           "departureAirport": "IKA",
           "arrivalAirport": "IST"
         },
         {
           "isDomestic": false,
           "departureAirport": "IST",
           "arrivalAirport": "LAX"
         }
      ]
    }
}
```

here is my c# classes that I use

```
public class Data
{
    public List<itineraries> itineraries { get; set; } = new List<itineraries>();
  
}
public class itineraries
{
    public bool isDomestic { get; set; }
    public string departureAirport { get; set; }
    public string arrivalAirport { get; set; }
}
```

here is the code that I use to deserialize

```
Data availableData= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);

foreach (var item in availableData.itineraries){
   Console.WriteLine($"departureAirport:{item.departureAirport}");
}
```

But I could not list the itineraries.

Comment: Hint: your json starts with the property "data". Where is that in your c# classes?

Comment: @gunr2171 I edited the question and the data property is added to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this classes

```
public class Itinerary
    {
        public bool isDomestic { get; set; }
        public string departureAirport { get; set; }
        public string arrivalAirport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Itinerary> Itineraries { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

and code

```
var availableData= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);

foreach (var item in availableData.data.Itineraries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"departureAirport:{item.departureAirport}");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. So, the Root object should be created and it should be deserialized instead.

Comment: @Mustafa Yes, or you can create it just using C#. You don't need json for this.

Answer (score -2):

first, you have to install Newtonsoft.Json from NuGet Manager
then use these classes instead of yours

```
  public class Itinerary
        {
            public bool isDomestic { get; set; }
            public string departureAirport { get; set; }
            public string arrivalAirport { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public List<Itinerary> Itineraries { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public Data data { get; set; }
        }
```

the convert code is

```
 var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```